# Passing a Mongo connection to JQuery code via socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, sockets

I am trying to create a global MongoDB connection in my node.js web app like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mconn = null;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://myHost:27017/users', function(err, udb) {     //open connection to MongoDB db
    if (!err){
        mconn = udb;
    }
    else
        console.error("Could not connect to sql: ", err);
});
```

Then, I want to pass this connection via a `socket.emit' event like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('updates', function(PEMSID){
         gps_helper.get_gps(PEMSID, conn, function(data){      //make initial query to GPS table for marker coordinates
            socket.emit('message', {message: data, mongoConnection: mconn});
         });
         intervalID = setInterval(function(){
             gps_helper.get_gps(PEMSID, conn, function(data){      //query GPS table for marker coordinates on an interval
                socket.emit('message', {message: data, mongoConnection: mconn});
             });
         }, 30000);
    });
```

This doesn't appear to be working, the 'mongoConnection' value is empty on the other side. Is it possible to send it this way?

Comment: You want to transfer a live object to a web browser over a socket from node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible: you can't generally serialize, and therefore transmit, opaque data types like network connections or file handles.

Consider the security risks if it *were* possible: malicious clients would have complete access to your database.

You're going to have to make some sort of interface where your client code is sending certain messages to the server, the server performs the appropriate database actions and sends back the results (again, make sure you don't make this interface too general so that malicious client code gets to execute random queries against your database).

Comment: What about things like google maps, can you pass those in this kind of way?

Comment: @gjw80 what part of Google Maps do you mean?